# What is this user agent? (... Applex*0TV...)

Tags: user-agent

This is incredibly odd, so I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

I am seeing a user agent hit our site with a user agent ID that I cannot identify. Furthermore, searching the web and all of the user agent search sites is proving fruitless. If this were some esoteric UA that I only see a few dozen times, I wouldn't care, but I'm seeing it between 130,000 and 200,000 times a day.

The user agent is always a varient of this pattern:

AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.9A336a (Applex*0TV; U; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X; en_us)

The key commonality is the AppleCoreMedia library used with "Applex*0TV" - my gut says that this is some sort of varient of Apple's iTV, except the iTVs identify themselves quite clearly as "AppleTV"...

...so, what *is* this? Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: It might be an Apple TV ("Applex*0TV") with a wonky char.

Comment: Sorry for responding to such an old question, but Matt's comment sparked an idea: could the x*0 be a corruption or some weird encoding of a trade mark symbol?